# What type of tool is an "extension"?

Tags: tools, engine

According to this [WikiHow article](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Spark-Plugs-in-a-Car), one of tools needed to change a spark plug is "an extension."  Is this a type of wrench?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tool referred to is an accessory for a ratchet/socket wrench setup. It simply allows one to access fasteners that are inside deep holes.

It has a female square drive on one end--this connects to the ratchet; and a male square drive on the other end--this connects to the socket.

### Extensions of various lengths

[image]

### Ratchet with Extension and Socket in place

[image: Ratchet with extension and socket]